# What to use instead of Contacts.Intents.UI.LIST_STARRED_ACTION to display starred contacts in com.android.contacts?

Tags: android

Currently, I use this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Contacts.Intents.UI.LIST_STARRED_ACTION));
```

Works perfectly, but Android Studio displays:

> 'LIST_STARRED_ACTION' is deprecated as of API 5: Android 2.0 (Eclair)

How to implement the same functionality (opening com.android.contacts displaying the starred contacts) without using deprecated code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)` It open contact book to pick contact. you can use `startActivityForResult()` or `startActivity()`

> N.B. It is only show whole contact list.

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't what I'm looking for if it shows the whole contact list instead of the starred contacts only.